# making my application by the default file opener of a certain file type

Tags: android, file

I am trying to make an application that opens a certain file type (similar to a spreadsheet app that opens csv files) but I can't find out how. All I need to do is ber able to set an intent to open that file and the method which contains the file path

UPDATE
I am not trying to open a file, i am trying to make my application be launched when another app wants to open my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you have to become an content provider for that particular file type. Becoming content provider does not assures that you'll be default provider though, when your application is installed android will notify user with option to make your application as default content provider. Now it's up to user if he chooses your app to be default. It's similar for having multiple Dialer's, android asks you which dialer would you like to use by default.

Comment: Ok, so how do I get my app to be a content provider?

Comment: please follow this tutorial from android, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Great explanation, again it must be stressed that your app will not become default unless it is chosen to do so by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Probably when we use intent with action_view  must be opened in corresponding view.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,"URI to your file location");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: No, i want my app to be launched when another app does that.